# Ruby: access values through tap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

I've got a `Calculator` class that reads like so:

```
class Calculator
  DEFAULTS = {
    price: 4.25, size: 10000
  }.freeze

  def initialize(lead)
    @lead = lead
  end

  def lead_attributes
    @lead.attributes.symbolize_keys.merge(DEFAULTS)
  end

  def hash # massively simplified
    lead_attributes.tap do |h|
      h[:total] = h[:price] * h[:size]
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is that the `hash` method always returns the values from `DEFAULTS` despite `@lead` having a `:price` of `6.50`  and a `:size` of `8000`. If I don't merge `DEFAULTS` into `@lead.attributes` I get a nil error:

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

In short, why aren't my attributes accessible when I tap them? I want to load `DEFAULTS` only if the matching `@lead` attribute is `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want use [`reverse_merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Hash/reverse_merge) (or just merge in the opposite direction), otherwise [`merge`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) will always override existing `@lead.attributes` with the defaults.

Change to `lead_attributes` to:

```
def lead_attributes
  @lead.attributes.symbolize_keys.reverse_merge(DEFAULTS)
end
```

Or:

```
def lead_attributes
  DEFAULTS.merge(@lead.attributes.symbolize_keys)
end
```

Comment: The reference to documentation on [`Hash#merge`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge) would be helpful here. Also, there is no method `Hash#symbolize_keys` in plain ruby.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! Tearing my hair out over that thing, ha.